# Combining two arrays jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays - for example `[8, 7, 6, 5]` and `[5, 6, 7]`. In what way can I recieve *new* array `[7, 6, 5]`. So order *must be as in first array* and *elements as in second*. 
And it can be different values in arrays, not only numbers.
Thanks.

Comment: I think your example and description contradict each other.

Comment: this has been asked before. I will try to find it if you show input and expected output using better examples

Comment: May be you miss '5' in result array for your sample?

Comment: Do you want the result to be the **intersection** of those two arrays?

Comment: my bad. sorry. new array must be [7,6,5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the result must be `[7,6,5]`, not `[8,7,6]`.

```
> a = [8, 7, 6, 5]; b = [5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
> a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) >= 0 })
[7, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

```
var tab1 = new Array(8, 7, 6, 5);
var tab2 = new Array(5, 6, 7);
var result = new Array();
var l = tab1.length;
for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if(tab2.indexOf(tab1[i]) >= 0)
        result.push(tab1[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Will that produce `[8, 7, 6]` like the OP mentions?

Comment: Thanks @alex I totally misunderstood the question. My answer was updated.